Applying KCL to calculate op-amp output across resistor

Full disclosure: this is related to an assignment, but I promise my goal here is solely to learn

I have an op-amp connected with a negative feedback loop, and I am trying to calculate the voltage across the resistor connected with the output pin.
The diagram looks as such:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here's what I have come up with so far:
v- = 2 = v+

I across 3k Ω resistor at top:
I = 666.7 uA (as pointed out by Spero ...)

I assume we need to use KVL, going clockwise at the top:
getting voltage output:
2 + 2 + Vx = 0
Vx = -4 V

I across the resistor:
-4/3k = -1.33 mA

From here I'm not sure how to obtain the voltage drop across the lower resistor ... I would appreciate being directed to relevant resources or help with understanding how we can get voltage across an op-amp in this type of arrangement, as in the method I can try working with because I am out of ideas.

V- = 0 (inputs at the same potential)

Inputs of an ideal op-amp draw no current at all. 666A through 3k would be 2 million volts.

As already pointed out, I- and I+ are zero ... vo=2 V.

Your calculations are so wrong, and there's so much missing from your reasoning, that I don't think simple pointers will do you any good. At the risk of criticism for solving a homework problem, I'll take you through every single snippet of my thinking as I analyse this circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Notice that I've labelled the polarity of voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across R1 in accordance with passive sign convention; current enters the resistor at the terminal with higher (more positive) potential. As it turns out here, it wouldn't matter, but if circumstances were different, getting this wrong can yield incorrect or confusing signs.
KCL tells us that current into the op-amp's inverting input (node Q) is the same as current through both source V1 and resistor R1, because there's nowhere for current to leave or enter that path. I've marked current all along the path as \$I\$.
Finding out how much current \$I\$ flows is easy. One of the defining characteristics of op-amps is that their inputs have such high resistance, that no current flows into or out of those inputs. In practice there may be some tiny current (called input bias current), but it's almost always so small as to be negligible, and we ignore it. There are times when you can't ignore it, but this isn't one of them, so:
$$ I = 0A $$
That means no current is flowing through R1, and we can use Ohm's law to determine the voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across that resistor:
$$ V_{R1} = I \times R_1 = 0A \times 3k\Omega = 0V $$
An informal application of KVL goes like this: let's say the potential at node Q is \$V_Q\$. Due to the potential difference of 2V across source V1, the more positive side being node A, we can say that A is 2V higher in potential than Q:
$$ V_A = V_Q + 2V $$
We can do the same when comparing A to OUT. The difference between between \$V_A\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$ will be whatever voltage \$V_{R1}\$ exists across R1:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= V_A + V_{R1} \\ \\
&= V_Q + 2V + 0V \\ \\
&= V_Q + 2V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
The last piece of the puzzle is \$V_Q\$. If we rearrange that last equation relating \$V_Q\$ to \$V_{OUT}\$, it becomes clear that there is feedback:
$$ V_Q = V_{OUT}-2V $$
A rise in output \$V_{OUT}\$ results is a rise at the op-amp's inverting input potential, \$V_Q\$, which means feedback is negative. With negative feedback, an op-amp adjusts its output to whatever potential is necessary to equalise its two inputs, inverting and non-inverting. In other words:
$$ V_Q = V_P $$
Node P is held at ground potential, 0V:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_P &= 0V \\ \\
V_Q &= V_P \\ \\
&= 0V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
With \$V_Q\$ known, \$V_{OUT}\$ is also known:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= V_Q + 2V \\ \\
&= 0V + 2V \\ \\
&= +2V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that "load" resistance R2 doesn't appear in any of those equations. That's because the op-amp decides what potential to apply to OUT, making that output essentially a voltage source, independent of its load. Unless that load draws more current than the op-amp can sink or source, the op-amp decides \$V_{OUT}\$. Feedback still occurs via R1 and V1, but that has nothing to do with R2.
We can calculate current R2 with a simple application of Ohm's law:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{R2} &= \frac{V_{R2}}{R_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{OUT}-0V}{R_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{2V}{3k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 667\mu A
\end{aligned}
$$

Overall it makes sense, thank you. But i have a question about the fundamental principle used here: The 2 v voltage source goes directly to I-, so why do we still consider it 0 based on some fact that Vq=Vp = 0 due to one of it being grounded and at 0 potential? Why couldnt we argue both are 2 because the 2 v source goes to I-? If this is because no current flows through the inputs, then is v1=v2=0 in every single op amp configuration???

@Ethicist $V_Q=V_P$ because "with negative feedback, an op-amp adjusts its output to whatever potential is necessary to equalise its two inputs". $V_Q$ is controlled by the op-amp itself, by adjusting its own output. $V_P$ is set by you, in this case, to 0V.

so then is this always the case for negative feedback loops, vq controlled by the op amp itself, and vp set by us?

This taught me a lot, I appreciate it

@Ethicist Yes, that's the idea, feedback is when an input is influenced by the output. Negative feedback has the consequence that the two inputs are equal in potential. Here is an answer explaining intuitively why this happens.

Initial answer
The resistors R1 and R2 are likely placed to mislead. They do not affect the op-amp output voltage because:

practically no current flows through R1 and its resistance is low, so the voltage drop across it is negligible,

the voltage across R2 does not depend on R2 resistance because it is produced by a constant voltage source (op-amp output).


So in practice, the circuit consists of an op-amp and a 2 V voltage source V2 connected between its output and its inverting input.
The op-amp is connected in a voltage follower configuration with zero input voltage at the non-inverting input and output voltage at the inverting input that follows the voltage at the non-inverting input.
The voltage source V2 acts as a disturbance for this "zero voltage follower" and the op-amp starts to compensate for it. To do this, it is forced to increase its output voltage to 2 V to zero the voltage at its inverting input.
V2 can be considered as a floating input voltage followed by the grounded op-amp output. In the classic op-amp voltage follower, the V2 "disturbance" (input voltage) is moved between the non-inverting input and ground; so it is grounded.
So, we can conclude that in negative feedback circuits the input voltage acts as a disturbance that is compensated by the amp output voltage, and this voltage is used as a circuit output.
Building scenario
Let's put this "philosophy" into practice by building a negative feedback circuit step by step.
Zero voltage follower
The simplest possible negative feedback system can be made by connecting the output of an inverting amplifier to its input.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage at the input of the amplifier is the output of the negative feedback circuit; the amplifier's role is to keep it at zero.

simulate this circuit
Disturbed zero voltage follower
Now, if we introduce a 1 V disturbance into the feedback loop, the op-amp will raise its output voltage VOA by 1 V to counteract this positive disturbance.

simulate this circuit
And v.v., if we insert a -1 V disturbance into the feedback loop, the op-amp will lower its output voltage by 1 V to counteract this negative disturbance.

simulate this circuit
Floating-input follower
Since the op-amp output follows the disturbing voltage, we can use this voltage as an input.

simulate this circuit

This input source is "floating" but we prefer grounded.
Grounded-input follower
Then let's move it between the non-inverting input and ground.

simulate this circuit
The result is the same.

Conceptualization
These specific op-amp circuits with negative feedback can be represented by a general conceptual diagram of three elements connected in a loop: an input voltage source Vin, an output voltage source Vout controlled by the difference Vd between the two voltages. We can make Vout adjust its voltage to zero the voltage difference Vd. As a result, Vout follows Vin.
The only difference between the versions is the grounding point.
Floating input, grounded output
This is the OP's circuit where the input voltage source is floating.

simulate this circuit
Grounded input, grounded output
This is the most preferred version where both input and output voltage source are grounded.

simulate this circuit
Grounded input, floating output
Although this configuration is possible, it is inconvenient to use because it requires an op-amp with a differential output.

simulate this circuit
Behavioral voltage source
We can automate the operation of these circuits by replacing the manually controlled source Vout with a behavioral (Vd-controlled) one. Let's take the OP's variant as an example to demonstrate this.

simulate this circuit
Conclusions

The most elementary negative feedback circuit is realized by directly connecting the output of an inverting amplifier to its input.

There is no input voltage in this configuration, and the output voltage is zero; the amplifier's role is to keep it at zero.

A voltage source inserted in the negative feedback loop disturbs this "zero voltage follower".

To compensate, the op-amp increases its output voltage by an equal amount.

So, the disturbing voltage can serve as a "floating" input voltage.

To make it grounded, it must be moved between the non-inverting input and ground.



Circuit analysis using simplified OpAmp equivalent circuit:


thank you francesco, can you explain the symbols a bit? what is Ro, Ad Vd etc.

Ad is the differential voltage gain or open loop gain of the OpAmp  (10^5). Ro is the output resistance of the OpAmp, Rid is the differential input resistance of the OpAmp, Vg is the input signal, Rf is the feedback resistor, R is the load resistance.

It's not so much a KCL/KVL type of problem, but more of an op-amp theory question.
An op-amp in closed loop (feedback from OUT to Vin(-)) will have its inputs at the at the same voltage. Any difference will be strongly amplified and presented to Vout. Also, for an ideal op-amp there's no input current, we'll come back to that in a bit.
We see that the Vin(+) input is grounded (0V.) Again, recall we have a closed loop, so Vin(-) also must be 0V. To bring the inputs back in balance, the op-amp needs to counteract V2 voltage source (+2V) inserted between Vin(-) and R1. The op-amp obliges us by bringing Vout to +2V.
That is, for a closed loop like we have,

Vin(+) = 0 (it's grounded)
Vin(-) = 0 (op-amp is closed loop)

The voltage present on Vin(-) is also going to be:

Vin(-) = V2 + Vout (KVL, yes.)

Substituting 0V for Vin(-), and rearranging to solve for Vout, we have:

Vout = V2 - Vin(-)
Vout = +2V - 0V = +2V

Remember we said there's no input current on Vin(-) or Vin(+). Therefore the R1 current is also zero (I suppose that would be KCL. Anyway.) Because of this, the R1 value is irrelevant. It could be zero, it could be many megaohms, same result.
Finally, since we know the op-amp is driving Vout to +2V, we find the R2 current:

I(R2) = Vout / R2 = +2V / 3k = 0.667 mA.

Here's a quick sim to confirm the calcs (simulate it here):

You'll notice that the Vin(-) input isn't exactly zero, it's -20uV. Also, the actual Vout voltage is 1.999980V, although Falstad won't show that. Why the difference? The op-amp has less than infinite gain (it's set to 100k in the sim). In reality all op-amps will have a slight voltage difference depending on the gain and the output voltage. More here: Ideal behavior of op-amps
For our purposes here however we can regard Vin(-) as practically zero, that is, as virtual ground.

First, let's replace the op-amp with its ideal equivalent: a voltage-controlled voltage source with infinite gain G:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the schematic I had to set \$G={10}^6\$ - a typical gain of a precision op-amp. The simulator only works with numbers, and infinity is not a number, so 1 million had to do :)
The voltage-controlled voltage source has no input current - same as an ideal op-amp. And, since it is a voltage source, the output impedance is zero, thus the load presented by R2 does not affect \$V_A\$.
Its output voltage
$$V_A = G\cdot(V_0-V_B) = G\cdot V_B = G\cdot(V_A-V_{R1}-V_{V2}) = G\cdot(V_A-V_{V2}),$$
and we note that \$V_{R1}=0\$ since there's no current flowing through R1.
We can now solve for \$V_A\$:
$$\begin{aligned}
V_A &= G\cdot(V_A-V_{V2}) \\
V_A &= G\cdot V_A - G\cdot V_{V2} \\
V_A\cdot(1-G) &= - V_{V2} \cdot G \\
V_A &= -V_{V2} \frac{G}{1-G} \\
V_A &= V_{V2} \frac{G}{G-1}.\\
\end{aligned}$$
An ideal op-amp has infinite gain G, thus G is not a number and we have to calculate the limit:
$$\begin{aligned}
V_A &= V_{V2} \cdot \lim_{G\to\infty} \frac{G}{G-1} \\
&= V_{V2} \cdot \lim_{G\to\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{G}-1} \\
&= V_{V2} \cdot \lim_{G\to\infty} \frac{1}{0-1} \\
&= V_{V2} \cdot 1 \\
&= V_{V2}\\
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, the output voltage \$V_A\$ is the same as the voltage on the source V2.
We can also see that a real op-amp with finite voltage gain G will deviate farther from the ideal the lower its gain is. As \$G\to1\$, the output will be just half of what it should be.


A very good idea (especially for this case) is to replace the real op-amp with an ideal element (VCVS). There is another option - a behavioral voltage source. I'm still hesitating which one to use because each of them has its advantages and disadvantages, but I'm more inclined to use the latter one... maybe because the schematic is not cluttered or due to the more meaningful voltage source symbol.
